# Rails validation fails but object memory remains unchanged?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, forms, model

First time user long time reader.  I have thoroughly looked for an explanation for the problem I'm having via the mighty search engine Google, but alas I have failed to produce any significant insight.

I need to be able to ensure that a model form is not reloaded with invalid data.  Since the model stored in memory on the server is edited directly with the parameters of the web form first, and THEN checked for validity, without additional code invalid model data will ALWAYS be sent back to the form.  This is less than desirable to me.  My question is this: **how do I ensure this doesn't happen?**

What I'm thinking is I need some mechanism for saving the state of the object before it's modified with the parameters sent from the web form, and then after a failed validation restore the object to it's previous, correct and unmodified state of being.

Help!

Thanks,
Les

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object isn't actually modified in the db if validation fails, even though the object is in an invalid state in the form ... the thinking behind this is that the user wants to see the errors they made so they can correct them.

If you don't want that to be the case, then just read back the object with a WhateverObject.find(x) and assign it to the variable that the form is referencing and it will 'restore' the object to its previous unmodified state.

Comment: Alternatively if you have the object already you can just do `my_obj.reload` to reload its state from the database.

Comment: That's true, it can be useful to see the errors you made.  In my specific case it's not really important, but that's an important point for me to remember in the future.

In my case I was able to call model.reload in the else clause of the update method in my model controller, worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

To add to what concept47 said you can also get the value for a particular field using 
  object.field_was
Have a look at ActiveRecord::Dirty for details (http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html)

Using that you could retrieve the original values for just those fields that had validation errors.